# Handling Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a little problem with the button in JQuery Mobile.

This is how I define the button:

```
<div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Sample</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
          <a id='btn' href='#' data-role='button' 
           data-icon='check' data-iconpos='right'>Click the button</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

And then I have a little script for the event-handling (inside the index.html):

```
        <script>                
            $("#btn").bind("click", function(event) {
                alert("click");
            });
        </script>
```

But unfortunately this doesnt work. :(

Can somebody help me? I'am new at JavaScript.

Comment: Did you try placing that inside `$(document).on('pageinit', function() { ...`

Comment: Is this page inside index.html? Or a different html file?

Comment: This is inside the index.html. Not a different. And @adeneo: Yeah i tried this and this doesnt work.

Comment: What version of JQM are you using? Pls post more details.

Comment: I'am using JQM with the version 1.4.0

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page_id", function () { $("#btn").on("click", function () { alert("clicked"); }); });` try binding it to `pagecreate` and make sure you give page div a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.on()` function:

```
    <script>  
      $(function(){            
        $("#btn").on("click", function(event) {
            alert("click");
        });
      });  
    </script>
```

If you need to add every time `$("#btn")` element to the event handler, you can use:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn",function(event) {...
```

**Edited with @Terry suggestion:**

You should also use `$(function(){ ...` to ensure the DOM is ready before binding the event.

Comment: Should try binding the event only when the DOM is ready, i.e. within the `$(function(){...});` enclosure.

Answer (score -1):

First off you should state a script `type`, like so:

`<script type="text/javascript"> [code here] </script>`

Then inside the script tags you should wrap any code you want executed once the page loads like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
             $("#btn").bind("click", function(event) {
                  alert("click");
             });
        });
    </script>
```